# Make specific product variations not taxable in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, settings, product-variations, tax

I manage a Woocommerce website that sells videos. Most of them are variable products with different product variations:

- A hard-copy DVD by mail
- Or a stream.

The streaming videos are, obviously, virtual products, so no shipping is charged and **taxes should not be charged.**

Is it possible to change the tax status for some variation? Ideally, I'd like to be able to have ALL "Streaming Video" variations to be not taxable by default, but I'd settle for being able to edit them one by one.

By default, I can change the tax CLASS for a variation, but I can't change the tax STATUS.

How can I make some product variations not taxable?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec Sorry it wasn't clear... The attribute "Streaming Video." So if there is a variable product with three variations (based on attributes), I'd like the "Streaming Video" variation to be tax-free in all instances. As I said, I'd settle for being able to change the tax status for the variations individually. Doesn't seem like an option.

Comment: But I do NOT want ALL of the variations to be not-taxable. Only the "Streaming Video" variation. The DVD variation should still be taxed.

Comment: Prices are already set excluding tax, so that's all fine. But I guess my question is still unclear. **HOW** do you set zero tax on related variations? It is not an option. I can change the tax class, but not the tax status.

Comment: I have finally answered, It will be more clear and easy to understand with screenshots… Tell me is that is enough clear and solved your issue. Please any feed back will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I appreciate it very much, and I think it'll work, but I haven't been able to implement it yet. With about 100 products to go through, I have to set aside a couple of hours to do it. Thank you! I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 3):

As taxable feature is not available for product variations, you will need to set zero taxes on those Product variations.

For that you need to go to in Woocommerce settings > Taxes (tab).

Then you will have to add a "Zero Rate" in "Additional tax classes" related field, and save:

[image]

A new "Zero Rate rates" setting tab will appear on the "Taxes" setting page:

[image]

Click on it and you will get the "Zero Rate" settings page. Insert a row this way and save:

[image]

Now on your variable products, in the variations, the Zero tax is available to be selected:

[image]

Select it for each variation and save them all. **You are done.**